# How do i edit form field value in MS WORD 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do i edit Text Form Field (legacy forms) in my document, so that i can then use new value of this field in my VBA script?

I have simple form with Text Form Field (Bookmark = TextFormField1). It is showing default text "default text".

I can access text of this field like this: `ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextFormField1").Range.Text`

However, if i change value of this field, it seems to delete the field itself, and replacing it with simple text - causing  `ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextFormField1").Range.Text` to throw exception, because TextFormField1 does not exist anymore...

What am i doing wrong? How can i insert text in form field, and use this text in my VBA script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Result` property:

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields("TextFormField1").Result = "Form field text"
```

Comment: For some reason in my Word 2013, it saves the text, but when editing the Form Field, the old text appears, leading to some form of corruption.

Comment: The @Вадим Онищенко solution is the current solution in MS Word 2013. This work, but with the corruption indicated above.   `ThisDocument.FormFields("Index_Or_FormFieldName_or_Bookmarkname").TextInput.EditType Type:=wdRegularText, Default:="Your Form field text" `

Answer (score 1):

Try next code:

```
ThisDocument.FormFields("Index_Or_FormFieldName_or_Bookmarkname").TextInput.EditType Type:=wdRegularText, Default:="Your Form field text"
```

But it rec the value in to the FormField very slowly.